# Powershell wait until after file download to continue script

Tags: powershell, start-process

```
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Method "Get" -uri $url -Headers $get_headers 
**Start-Process "chrome.exe" $x.url**
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Hello,

I am using the above to download a file via chrome. Is it possible to wait until the file download is complete to continue the script instead of sleeping or implementing an incremental retry function.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried using Start-Process `"chrome.exe" $x.url -wait`; Also why not just do another `Invoke-Restmethod` and save the file?

Comment: unfortunately -wait did not work. Invoke-RestMethod -outfile seems to be working quite well. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So lets talk about what i see and ways to make it better

```
$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Method "Get" -uri $url -Headers $get_headers 
Start-Process "chrome.exe" $x.url
Start-Sleep -s 10
```

Well you can save using the **Invoke-RestMethod**

Here is a example

```
Invoke-RestMethod "http://www.peoplelikeus.org/piccies/codpaste/codpaste-teachingpack.pdf" -OutFile "C:\codpaste-teachingpack.pdf"
```

In your case this might work.

```
$x = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Headers $get_headers 
Invoke-RestMethod $x.url -OutFile "C:\SomeTypeOfFile.Txt"
```

The **Invoke-RestMethod** will wait until it is complete to move on in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Invoke-RestMethod $x.url -OutFile "C:\SomeTypeOfFile.Txt" is working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

FYI (putting this here as it is too long for a normal comment), here are [3 other ways](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell), that you could have done this:

```
$url = "http://mirror.internode.on.net/pub/test/10meg.test"
$output = "$PSScriptRoot\10meg.test"
$start_time = Get-Date


# 1. Invoke-WebRequest

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output
"Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"

# 2. System.Net.WebClient

(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $output)
"Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"

# 3. Start-BitsTransfer

Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output -Asynchronous
"Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
```